# jOOQ: Is there a restriction in the DDLDatabase generator for deferrable constraints?

Tags: sql, code-generation, ddl, jooq

I'm using the DDLDatabase generator from Gradle to generate jOOQ sources. I seem to have hit a snag when it comes to deferrable constraints.

Generating from a live database for the same DDL works...

Here's my configuration for DDLDatabase:

```
jooq {
  version = "3.11.11"
  edition = "OSS"

  reference(sourceSets.main) {
    generator {
      database {
        name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase"
        properties {
          property {
            key = "scripts"
            value = "schema-gen/schema.sql"
          }
          property {
            key = "sort"
            value = "semantic"
          }
        }
        inputSchema = "REFERENCE"
      }
      generate {
        relations = true
        deprecated = false
        records = true
        immutablePojos = false
        fluentSetters = true
      }
      target {
        packageName = "com.octeris.aml.reference.persistence.jooq"
        directory = "jooq-gen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the part of the DDL the generator stumbles at:

```sql
create table reference.a (
  id varchar(100) not null
 ,foo_id varchar(100)
 ,constraint a$c$p primary key (id)
 ,constraint a$f$1 foreign key (foo_id) references reference.b(id) on delete restrict on update restrict deferrable initially deferred
);
```

the error reported is the following:

`Token ')' expected: [8:106] ...rence.b(id) on delete restrict on update restrict [*]deferrable initially deferred`

Does anyone know of an alternative syntax that would be accepted? Or is this potentially a bug in the generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ parser doesn't recognise this syntax yet. I've created a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8799

#### jOOQ 3.11 workaround

Right now, the workaround is to preprocess the SQL files before you pass them to the `DDLDatabase`. You should search for the `deferrable initially deferred` syntax and replace it by an empty string.

#### jOOQ 3.12 workaround

Note that starting from the upcoming jOOQ 3.12, there will be a new jOOQ-specific comment syntax where you can comment out such syntax elements only for the jOOQ parser, while they keep being executed by your database. The feature request is this one:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8325

The feature will work like this (this is what will be executed in the database):

```sql
create table reference.a (
  id varchar(100) not null
 ,foo_id varchar(100)
 ,constraint a$c$p primary key (id)
 ,constraint a$f$1 
    foreign key (foo_id) 
    references reference.b(id) 
    on delete restrict 
    on update restrict 
    -- [jooq ignore start]
    deferrable initially deferred
    -- [jooq ignore stop]
);
```

jOOQ will ignore everything between those two markers, so this will be what jOOQ parses

```sql
create table reference.a (
  id varchar(100) not null
 ,foo_id varchar(100)
 ,constraint a$c$p primary key (id)
 ,constraint a$f$1 
    foreign key (foo_id) 
    references reference.b(id) 
    on delete restrict 
    on update restrict 
    -- [jooq ignore start]
    -- [ ... ignored ... ]
    -- [jooq ignore stop]
);
```

The SQL doesn't need to be formatted this way. I just did this for this question here. You could also use `/* [jooq ignore start] */` on a one liner SQL statement.

The exact token that delimits the parts to be ignored by jOOQ can be specified by:

- `Settings.parseIgnoreCommentStart`
- `Settings.parseIgnoreCommentStop`

Comment: Thank you. Is there a rough ETA for 3.12? I've seen that the milestone "completion percentage" is at 85%, so I reckon it'll take a few more months, correct?

Comment: It should be released in June/July 19

Comment: Cool, sooner than expected - looking forward to it!